# How to take incomplete waiting times into account

Tags: censoring, interarrival-time

I am measuring the time between jumps from a jump process. However my observation window starts randomly somewhere in time. Therfore I do not know when the jump before the first observed one occurs. The same thing happens when my observation window ends. In order to have sufficient data I make these observations multiple times.

Up till now I have just disregarded the first and last measured intervals.

How can I include the 'incomplete' times in order to estimate at least the mean and variance, better yet the distribution of waiting times.

Comment: Thanks for adding the 'censoring' tag. Didn't know that term. That means that some of my times are 'right censored' and some are 'left censored'. Now how can I include those values?